# Transition on mouse out is not working

Tags: html, css, transition

In my scenario, i have try many combinations, but i'm not able to figure out why the transition not work on mouse out. Hope in your helps... Thanks!

CSS:

```
.wrap_img {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #555;
}

.play-icon-hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.play-icon-hover i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 90px;
}

.wrap_img:hover .play-icon-hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap_img">
  <a href="" title="">
    <div class="play-icon-hover">
      <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/L41kgye3/10/

Comment: You're toggling `visibility : hidden` which is not animatable (grammar?). It just hides instantly.

Comment: Why did you undo the code snippet I had made?

Comment: @JeremyThille because isn't working... it doesn't show play icon.

Comment: ...because you didn't include FontAwesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your transition is not working on mouseout is that you have used `opacity 0.5s ease-in-out` in your css whereas you have also used visibility: hidden on your css selector `.play-icon-hover`. So you need to use `transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out`. Try this code.

```
.play-icon-hover {
    position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Change to this:

```
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
```